# add or subtract 1 from a row in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, rest, sum, 2d

So I got this 2D Array that is a 5x5 array and I have to subtract or add 1 to one of the rows that the user chooses to change. All is fine when the user inputs to change the first row, but with the higher rows, for example 2, it adds more than 1.

The array values are

```
 1 -2  1  0  0
-1  0  4  2  0
 0 -4  1 -1  0
 0  1 -1 -1 -2
 0 -3  1 -1  0
```

And the method I used to add 1 is the following

```
public static void plusRow (int i){
       for(int row = 0; row < board.length; row++){
           int[] rows = board[i];
           for(int col = 0; col < board.length; col++){
               rows[col] = rows[col] + 1; 
               System.out.print(board[row][col] + " ");
           }
           System.out.println("");
       }
   }
```

My output value for example with 2 comes out like this

```
1 -2 1 0 0 
1 2 6 4 2 
0 -4 1 -1 0 
0 1 -1 -1 -2 
0 -3 1 -1 0
```

When it should be

```
1 -2 1 0 0 
0 1 5 3 1 
0 -4 1 -1 0 
0 1 -1 -1 -2 
0 -3 1 -1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your nested for loop runs as many times as the function input int "i"

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is very inefficient-  you don't need to do a nested loop here.  Break your ouput and your math into 2 different loops.

```
for(int j =0; j<boards[i].length; j++){
   boards[i][j] += 1;
}
```

Then write a double loop to ouput board.  In fact, that should be a separate function